# g++ and boost linker error after upgrade

Tags: 11.10, package-management, g++

I am getting the following problems.  I am sure it is a package that was not install/upgraded properly, I am not sure which one:

```
$ make
g++ -I/usr/include/boost -MM ./YYY.cc ./main.cc ./myClass.cc > buildfiles.d
g++ -Wno-deprecated -Wall -ansi -O2 -I/usr/include/boost   -c -o YYY.o YYY.cc
g++ -Wno-deprecated -Wall -ansi -O2 -I/usr/include/boost   -c -o main.o main.cc
g++ -Wno-deprecated -Wall -ansi -O2 -I/usr/include/boost   -c -o myClass.o myClass.cc
g++ -o prog -Wno-deprecated -Wall -ansi -O2 -I/usr/include/boost -L/usr/lib -lstdc++ -lboost_program_options -lboost_thread ./YYY.o ./main.o ./myClass.o
./YYY.o: In function `void boost::call_once<void (*)()>(boost::once_flag&, void (*)())':
YYY.cc:(.text._ZN5boost9call_onceIPFvvEEEvRNS_9once_flagET_[void boost::call_once<void (*)()>(boost::once_flag&, void (*)())]+0x14): undefined reference to `boost::detail::get_once_per_thread_epoch()'
YYY.cc:(.text._ZN5boost9call_onceIPFvvEEEvRNS_9once_flagET_[void boost::call_once<void (*)()>(boost::once_flag&, void (*)())]+0x2c): undefined reference to `boost::detail::once_epoch_mutex'
YYY.cc:(.text._ZN5boost9call_onceIPFvvEEEvRNS_9once_flagET_[void boost::call_once<void (*)()>(boost::once_flag&, void (*)())]+0x62): undefined reference to `boost::detail::once_epoch_mutex'
YYY.cc:(.text._ZN5boost9call_onceIPFvvEEEvRNS_9once_flagET_[void boost::call_once<void (*)()>(boost::once_flag&, void (*)())]+0x67): undefined reference to `boost::detail::once_epoch_cv'
YYY.cc:(.text._ZN5boost9call_onceIPFvvEEEvRNS_9once_flagET_[void boost::call_once<void (*)()>(boost::once_flag&, void (*)())]+0x95): undefined reference to `boost::detail::once_epoch_mutex'
[...]
```

Just top be clear, the headers are installed and included in the .h files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution involved changing the order of linkage, as per the man page.  The thing is that it used to work fine with an older version of g++...

```
$ make
g++ -I/usr/include/boost -MM ./YYY.cc ./main.cc ./myClass.cc > buildfiles.d
g++ -ansi -O2 -Wall -I/usr/include/boost   -c -o main.o main.cc
g++ -ansi -O2 -Wall -I/usr/include/boost   -c -o myClass.o myClass.cc
g++ -o prog -ansi -O2 -Wall -I/usr/include/boost  ./YYY.o ./main.o ./myClass.o -lstdc++ -L/usr/lib -lboost_program_options -lboost_thread
```